# I want to change the time zone

Tags: php, wordpress, time, timezone

The time zone is set to +0. I want to set it to +3. The developer said changing from line 226 but I couldn't understand it.

https://prnt.sc/1sydawk

**$current_time = current_time('H:i a');** this line

```
$foodbakery_full_data = get_post_meta($restaurant_type_id, 'foodbakery_full_data', true);
                                        if (!isset($foodbakery_full_data['foodbakery_opening_hours_element']) || $foodbakery_full_data['foodbakery_opening_hours_element'] == 'on') {
                                            if (isset($opening_hours_list) && !empty($opening_hours_list) && is_array($opening_hours_list)) {
                                                $current_day = strtolower(date('l'));
                                                $current_close = false;
                                                $current_day_text = esc_html__('Open', 'foodbakery');
                                                $closed_flag = false;
                                                $current_time = current_time('H:i a');
                                                $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
                                                $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $opening_hours_list[$current_day]['opening_time']);
                                                $date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $opening_hours_list[$current_day]['closing_time']);
```

Comment: You need to tag the question with whatever language it's written in.

Comment: Wordpress plugin file.

Comment: It's PHP then ?

Comment: If time and timezone is set to utc, then I think you should look at `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php` and make that a call beforehand to set the timezone to what you want or need, then reset it afterwards. Welcome to time hell...